# Load csv from Google Drive to Bigquery automaticly

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, google-drive-api

I am looking for a way to insert csv in Bigquery table when uploaded in Google Drive automatically.
I want to limit user action to just one. Drop csv in his Drive folder.
I tried with push notification From Drive API with no success.
What would be the best architecture?

kind regards

Comment: This isn't the right place for software architecture questions. Apart from using the push notifications, what did you try? I'm thinking you can have an Apps Script time based trigger to check the contents of a Drive folder, and if a csv was put in the folder, do the routine to upload to BigQuery, then remove the uploaded csv from the watched folder.

Comment: I tried  push notifications api with cloud function. But unfortunately got a 401, didn't succeed to register a domain with cloud function URL. Indeed with apps script will be easy but its lot of code and hardly maintainable. I was looking for a solution with cloud functions / pub_sub/ push notification.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/816559 you should ask this question in a different forum.